# Binary cross etropy loss with non binary ground truth data

Tags: loss-functions, cross-entropy, log-loss

Is it possible to use binary cross etropy loss with non binary ground truth data, i.e. not `[0,1]` values, but `[0,0.1,0.5,1.0]` values.

1. Does it make sense?
2. Does it have any side effects?

Comment: Could you explain (a) what "binary cross entropy loss" would actually be with such data; (b) exactly what your data are measuring; and (c) what you mean by "use"?

Comment: This topics answer my question https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/296277 https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443301